# What is the best way to have multiple configurations for one web application

Tags: asp.net, web-config

We have effectively one web application which is used by 3 different parts of the business, each with their own (although structurally identical) database.

Is it possible to have a different web.config per domain? Or is there a better way to handle this? Indeed is there a strong argument to have 3 separate web applications (even if that does mean maintaining 3 different deploys)

Comment: What kind of configuration changes between the websites? is it just connection-strings and app-settings or also `system.web`/`system.webserver` settings? in other words, is it just application settings or also web server settings?

Comment: It is just connection string settings and a handful of appsettings

Answer (score 0):

Externalize the `<appSettings />` and `<connectionStrings />` sections of the web.config.

For example, you have the appSettings read from a file called `applicationsettings.config` that lives under a subfolder called `WebConfiguration`, you would have:

```
<appSettings configSource="WebConfiguration\applicationsettings.config" />
```

Then inside the `WebConfiguration\applicationsettings.config` file, you have:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Setting1" value="Value1" />
  <add key="Setting2" value="Value2" />
</appSettings>
```

Simply configure the per-environment settings within each environment and the core web.config does not need to change between environments.

In my current project, we do this and by excluding the externalized files from source control, we can safely deploy to multiple environments without having to worry about overriding the environment-specific settings.

Comment: There is only one environment. Different urls all point to the same server. But depending on the url different databases are used. Would this work with this scenario?